# Do I need microcode update if I update Kernel?

Tags: linux, spectre, zombieload, fallout

There is a CPU vulnerability Microarchitectural Fill Buffer Data Sampling.
I use a Linux OS and I think  to fix Microarchitectural Fill Buffer Data Sampling you need to update intel microcode or update kernel to a fixed one https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2018-12130

I updated kernel to a kernel where Microarchitectural Fill Buffer Data Sampling is fixed. After that I run [spectre-meltdown-checker](https://github.com/speed47/spectre-meltdown-checker) and I get STATUS: VULNERABLE to all 4 types of MFBDS. Why ?

```
 CVE-2019-11091 aka 'RIDL, microarchitectural data sampling uncacheable memory (MDSUM)'
* Mitigated according to the /sys interface:  NO  (Vulnerable: Clear CPU buffers attempted, no microcode; SMT disabled)
* Kernel supports using MD_CLEAR mitigation:  YES  (found md_clear implementation evidence in kernel image)
* Kernel mitigation is enabled and active:  NO 
* SMT is either mitigated or disabled:  YES 
> STATUS:  VULNERABLE  (Vulnerable: Clear CPU buffers attempted, no microcode; SMT disabled)
```

Comment: Are you running the new kernel or did you just install it?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich MDSUM is not a different problem, it is a special case of all the other MDS vulnerabilities. A processor that is vulnerable to MDSUM is also vulnerable to at least one of the other MDS vulnerabilities, and vice versa. In addition, `spectre-meltdown-checker` does not distinguish between different MDS vulnerabilities and emits the same output for all of them. This makes it conservative, i.e., it may tell you that a processor is vulnerable even though it isn't.

Comment: @HadiBrais: thanks for pointing out the relation between the bugs.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you need both.  The Linux-side changes make use of the microcode-side changes to mitigate these vunlerabilities, *both* are needed for it to work.

Note that you also need to disable hyperthreading if you are really serious about mitigating this.

I should add, Intel published details on how to "maybe-perhaps" mitigate it partially using some code sequences, and those work even without the Microcode changes.  At least one of the BSDs deployed these, but Linux *did not* (and there are no plans to, either. Apparently, they don't mitigate things nearly enough to be worth the hassle).

Comment: Can you link to some of the "maybe-perhaps mitigations"?

Comment: @forest I think the answer is referring to the software sequences, which are an alternative to the new behavior of `VERW`. Each microarchitecture has its own sequence to clear its vulnerable buffers. You can see them in the FreeBSD source code [here](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/0f461ea9259ee2768bdd705db8e3d546b113fd57/sys/amd64/amd64/support.S#L1635). These are used [here](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/0444f8686dbe2bb10b0e53c7493beab30e4fb3f6/sys/x86/x86/cpu_machdep.c#L986) when the `MD_CLEAR` microcode update is not available or when `hw.mds_disable` is set to 2.

Comment: For example, the sequence for Ivy Bridge is called `mds_handler_ivb` in the FreeBSD source code. All of the sequences are defined by Intel in [this](https://software.intel.com/security-software-guidance/insights/deep-dive-intel-analysis-microarchitectural-data-sampling) article.